# Google Cloud Functions error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: google-cloud-functions

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource
>
> Failed to load
>   https://us-central1-social-post-builder-2.cloudfunctions.net/stripe-test-charge: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I had just added the cors module to express (on Google Cloud Functions)  and it seemed to be a partial fix, because a response object now returns (before, undefined was passed, breaking the page).

Now I get the above error in the console. Page doesn't break. Does my code below not allow all domains?

```
// https://us-central1-social-post-builder-2.cloudfunctions.net/stripe-test-charge

const app = require("express")();
const stripe = require("stripe")("test_api_key_removed");
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(require("body-parser").text());

exports.charge_card = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let {status} = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 2000,
      currency: "usd",
      description: "An example charge",
      source: req.body
    });
    res.json({status});
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).end();
  }
};
```

The package.json file for the above includes the latest packages as of today.

I don't think the React code needs to be shown, but just in case it is relevant, here is the React component that executes the fetch:

```
// CheckoutForm.js

import React, {Component} from "react";
import { CardElement, injectStripe } from "react-stripe-elements";

class CheckoutForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            complete : false
        };
    }

    async submit (event) {
    // User clicked submit
        let {token} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});
        console.log('CheckoutForm:16, token:', token)
        let response = await fetch("https://us-central1-social-post-builder-2.cloudfunctions.net/stripe-test-charge", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
            body: token.id
        });

        if (response.ok) console.log("Purchase Complete!")
    };

    render(props) {

        // render variables
        if (this.state.complete) return <h1>Purchase Complete</h1>;

        return (
            <div className='checkout'>
                <p>
                    Would you like to complete the purchase?
                </p>
                <CardElement />
                <button onClick={ this.submit } >
                    Send
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

Comment: If `https://us-central1-social-post-builder-2.cloudfunctions.net/stripe-test-charge` is the real URL, the problem seems to be that the response is 500 error response instead of a success response.

Comment: strange, an associate just got it working. I'll have to ask him about this

Comment: Hi! Any update with this? Did your associate fix the issue?

Comment: He did, I have not had the time to review the solution yet but it does work. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad to hear! If you find some time, could you post the solution as an answer and  [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) after two days? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! We will revisit this next week